# Magento 2 update multiple product price

Tags: magento2, php

i'm new with magento 2. I want to load products by id, and then change the price for each products.

Phtml :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($csv3); $i++) { 
    $product=$this->getLoadProduct($csv3[$i][0]);
    $product->setPrice($csv3[$i][1]);

    try {
        $product->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<pre>" .$e. "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Block :

```
public function getLoadProduct($id)
{
    return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

$csv3 is a variable contain data from reading csv file, csv3[x][0] is id, and csv3[x][1] is price.
I'm trying to update the price of each product with code above, but nothing happen.
Is there any solution for updating multiple product by id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried from frontend then you must set secure param in register. So try following way:

Inside Block

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {

    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

and set secure area

```
public function setSecureArea()
{
    $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
}
```

Now add following code before save from phtml template

```
$block->setSecureArea();
```

Also modify your *getLoadProduct* method following code

```
public function getLoadProduct($id)
{
    return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id, true);
}
```